# Join does not return value when one of the tables in the joins does not have the record

Tags: sql

I have this stored procedure. My problem is when record is not existed in Agency Table is does not return anything. I would like to say even if there is no record in Agency still return so I have added the left outer JOIN for Agency and _Agency = IsNull(U._Agency,'')
At the top. But still does not return value. It is returning value when I take A._IsActive = 1 
At the last line out.
What should I do id  A._IsActive
Has no value still return. I tried same ISNull but not working.

```
declare @Username   VARCHAR(50)
,   @Password   VARCHAR(50)

set @Username = 'admin'
set @Password = 'password2'

SELECT U.Username
 ,_Partner = u.AID
 ,_Agency = IsNull(U._Agency,'')
 , UR._Role
 ,R.Name 
FROM [PartnerPortal].[dbo].[User] AS U
left outer JOIN [PartnerPortal].[dbo].Agency AS A 
  ON U._Agency = A._IdxIdentity 
JOIN [PartnerPortal].[dbo].User_Role AS UR 
  ON U._IdxIdentity = UR._User
JOIN [PartnerPortal].[dbo].[Role] AS R 
  ON UR._Role = R._IdxIdentity
WHERE (Username = @Username)
  AND [Password] =@Password
  AND U._IsActive = 1 
  AND A._IsActive = 1  
  AND UR._IsActive = 1 
  AND R._IsActive = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
...
left outer JOIN [PartnerPortal].[dbo].Agency AS A 
    ON U._Agency = A._IdxIdentity 
...
WHERE ... A._IsActive = 1
```

When `Agency` has no matching row, all columns returned for that table are `null`, but you are requiring that `_IsActive` be `1`, which will *not* be true for left joins.

Move that condition into the `ON` condition of the left join:

```
...
left outer JOIN [PartnerPortal].[dbo].Agency AS A 
    ON U._Agency = A._IdxIdentity 
    AND A._IsActive = 1
...
WHERE ...
```

Now the condition will apply *if there's a matching row*, or you'll get the all-null row if there's no matching row.